# Call second Javascript function only after the form created in the first Javascript Function has been created

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to create an application with dynamic forms. I would like on-screen calculations for these forms but I am struggling. I can get the JS to work when it is a static webpage and now I'm attempting to get that logic working for a dynamic page.

I believe what I am after is for the on-screen calculations JS function only to be called after the form has been created. However, I may just not understand the basis of HTML / JS - I'll let you decide that...

The original page that when the drop down is changed the "form" is created (Basically - On drop down change, load Page2.php into div "ForecastForm", then using the input boxes & divs in Page2.php, the 2nd JS function aims to provide on-screen calculations):

```
<div>Top</div>
<br></br>
<script>
function GetForm(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("ForecastForm").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("ForecastForm").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","Page2.php?text="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
</script>

<select id="SiteDD" onchange="GetForm(this.value)">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
<div id="ForecastForm"><b></b></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
for(var x=1; x<3; x++){

let num = "num"+x;
let input = "input"+x;
let total = "total"+x;
let element = "element"+x;
let inputelement = "inputelement"+x;
let thesum = "thesum"+x;

element = document.getElementById(num),
inputelement = document.getElementById(input),
thesum = document.getElementById(total);
document.getElementById(input).onchange = function() {
thesum.innerHTML = parseInt(element.innerHTML) + parseInt(inputelement.value);
};
};
</script>

<br></br>

<div>Bottom</div>
```

and the "Form" that gets loaded:

```
<div id="num1">11</div>

<input type=number value=2 id="input1">

<div id="total1">0</div>

<br>
<br>

<div id="num2">11</div>

<input type=number value=2 id="input2">

<div id="total2">0</div>
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to bind event handlers before the dynamic content is loaded, so no `num1`, `num2`, nor `num3` elements will be found during the execution of your `for` loop (the same happens for the other elements).

Instead, use the principle of event delegation: the `change` event will bubble up, so although the triggering `input` element is not yet there, you can already listen to the `change` event on the document. When later the `input` is added to the document, and generates the `change` event, your event handler will capture that event as it bubbles up the DOM hierarchy.

Instead of your `for` loop, you could use code along these lines:

```
function calculate() {
    document.getElementById('total' + SiteDD.value).textContent =
        +document.getElementById('num' + SiteDD.value).textContent +
        +document.getElementById('input' + SiteDD.value).value;
}

document.onchange = function(e) {
    // Check if this event was triggered from the input element we want to
    // listen to. If so, call the calculate function:
    if (e.target.id === 'input' + SiteDD.value) calculate();
};
```

You could also call the *calculate* function as soon as the dynamic content has been injected:

```
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            ForecastForm.innerHTML = this.responseText;
            calculate(); // <---
        }
    };
```

Comment: sorry I gave a bad example. what is selected in the drop down list has no baring on the calculation - it could have been a,b,c etc but both calculations on the form created still needed to happen.  Currently with your code, the only calculations are happening depends on what is selected. i.e - if 2 is selected only input2 + num2 = total2 happens. when 1 is selected only input1 + num1 = total1 happens etc. Thats why I had the for loop because the number of calculations in the form will vary in reality. thank you for the help, this is the 2nd time you've helped me - owe you big time!

Comment: I managed to get it to work. Thank you for taking the time to run through your code, really helped me get to the answer. I changed to the following if you are interested: function calculate() {

for(var x=1; x<3; x++){

    document.getElementById('total' + x).textContent =
        +document.getElementById('num' + x).textContent +
        +document.getElementById('input' + x).value;
}

}

document.onchange = function(e) {
    // Check if this event was triggered from the input element we want to
    // listen to. If so, call the calculate function:
 calculate();
}; thanks again

Comment: Ah yes, I thought the value of `x` corresponded to the selected option. But good you found how to adapt it to your needs!